# ListView UI doesn't look as expected.(Native-Base)

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, react-native, native-base

[image]

Why is it showing ugly left grey margin? I tried with many different List and it's still printing left grey margin. Is this common?

I followed Native-base document : http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#list-avatar-headref

```
import { Container, Content, List, ListItem, Text, Left, Body, Thumbnail } from 'native-base';
import { View, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

...
render() { 
   return (
     <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Content>
          <List>
            {this._renderProfile()}
            <ListItem>
              <Left>
                <Text>! Edit Profile</Text>
              </Left>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem onPress={this._changePassword}>
              <Left>
                <Text>Change Password </Text>
              </Left>
            </ListItem>

            <ListItem>
              <Left>
                <Text>! Language Setting</Text>
              </Left>
            </ListItem>

            <ListItem onPress={this._showModal}>
              <Left>
                <Text>Logout</Text>
              </Left>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Content>
        {this._drawModal()}
      </View>
```

p.s Do you like using Native-Base for UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use like this:

```
render() {
        return (
            <ListItem style={{marginLeft: -15, paddingLeft: 15}}>
                <Left>
                    <Text>! Language Setting</Text>
                </Left>
            </ListItem>
        );
    }
```

and you should add avatar or icon. exm: `<ListItem icon | avatart />`

Comment: GREAT! It worked! How did you come up with -15 and 15 for marginLeft and paddingLeft? Does `15` work on every mobile?

Comment: There is a 15 space left to be cross platform. method works properly. I'm using too.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this but its works fine for me.
i think you should check your parent file if margin on left side.
so i prefer 100% parent width.

Comment: This is not an answer it's a comment. Or add more explanation to what you mean.

Comment: I checked my parent file but actually this was attached to the Root so your answer doesn't count on this problem! Thanks though!